# How to pass as input of a mex function an integer value?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to pass as argument of a mexfunction, an integer representing the number of columns for mxCreateDoubleMatrix. This integer is not supposed to be used anywhere else than in the main mexFunction.

Somehow, this doesn't seem to work.

```
// mex function for calling c++ code .
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    char *input_buf;
    size_t buflen;
    double ncols;
    double *result_final;
    double *result_second;

    /* get the length of the input string */
    buflen = (mxGetM(prhs[0]) * mxGetN(prhs[0])) + 1;

    /* copy the string data from prhs[0] into a C string input_ buf.    */
    input_buf = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);

    /* copy the int from prhs[0] to decide on length of the results.    */
    ncols = (int) (size_t) mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, ncols, mxREAL);
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, ncols, mxREAL);
    result_final = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    result_second = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);

    /* Do the actual computations in a subroutine */
    subroutine(input_buf, buflen, result_final, result_second);
}
```

If I take out the ncols line, all the rest works as expected. I did not include ncols as input to subroutine because it is not actually used there but only in the main, to define the size of the output array.

I am expected to have a matrix of 1x100 for the output array if I call myfun('examplefile.txt',100) instead the matrix that is shown at the end of the call has an infinite/very long number of columns.

Someone can help with this?

Comment: You access `prhs[0]` and `prhs[1]` without knowing if they exist. You should always test for input variables first. If you accidentally call your MEX-function with too few input arguments, your MATLAB will crash, instead of just giving an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the pointer to the value into a `size_t` and then an `int`. But its a pointer, an adress in RAM of the location of the value, not the value itself.

```
 ncols = (int) (size_t) mxGetPr(prhs[1]); %mex Get Pointer!!
```

Get the value instead.

```
 ncols = (int)(mxGetScalar(prhs[1]));
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason MatLab just crashes.

Comment: @Marseille this does not make MATLAB crash, I use it on my code continuously. A MATLAB crash is generally caused by a segmentation fault. Try this but do not call `subroutine`, I suspect the error is somewhere else, possibly in subroutine you access the array out of bounds. It makes sense, you do not give it the size, how does that function know how long the arrays are?

Comment: You are right. It works without call to subroutine. But I don't quite understand why.  The same exact function works if I don't have the number of columns as an input, but if I change the number inside the function manually for whatever value the array will be produced and correctly computed.

Comment: @Marseille There is no way I can answer why it does not work without seing the function. I suggest you accept this answer and post a different question with the function included. But the most likely case is simply that you are accessing `result_final` with an index bigger or equal to `ncols`. `result_final[ncols*2]` will cause a segfault and a MATLAB crash.